# Слова благодарности

Tags: этимология, грамотная-речь

В каких случаях применяются слова *благодарю* и *благодарствую*?
Также — вопрос по этимологии слова *спасибо*. И вспомним прошлое про слово *дякую*.

В чём разница этих слов?

Answer (score 1):

По значению слова идентичны. Разница состоит в том, что слово *благодарствую* является устаревшим (http://dic.academic.ru/dic.nsf/ushakov/747870) и в наше время используется почти исключительно для придания выражению благодарности комического оттенка. См. также http://slovo.dn.ua/blagodartvuju-spasibo-blagodarju.html.

Answer (score 1):

Первые два слова — от *дарю во благо* (жертвую на благое), говорят о добром отношении к чему-то или кому-то. Одно из них, *благодарствую* (благодарственно жертвую), — старомодно, а другое устаревает на глазах, хотя по смыслу более уместно, чем превосходящее его по популярности *спасибо*.

*Спасибо* — слово, а точнее, его составляющие упоминаются летописями с дохристианских времён. В его первой части заложен призыв спастись, в смысле «спасися (*устремися*) раю прекрасный», и во второй упоминается конкретное божество. В этом слове есть та же связь с благодарственными жертвами, но здесь — *спасительными* от *Спас*, *Спаситель* = *избавитель от бед и несчастий*. Несмотря на то, что  *спасися* иногда в церковных книгах берётся вместо *прощай*, в церковной лексике слова *спасибо* нет. Как нет «большого спасибо» и «великого дякую».

С некоторым опозданием — цитата очень к месту: «Рудименты национального бытия сохраняются, но, как правило, не осознаются носителями советскости подобно тому, как русские безрелигиозные люди говорят «спасибо», вовсе забыв, что в действительности желают, чтобы Бог спас того, кого они благодарят». http://www.ng.ru/ideas/2013-11-08/5_russkost.html